# Jest error "Component x is not resolved" when computing the templateUrl at build time

Tags: angular, jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I have an Angular 14 application using Jest for unit testing. For some reason not worth mentioning here we need to compute the templateUrl during build time like this:

```
const suff = "v1";
@Component({
  ...
  templateUrl: `./my-comp${suff}.component.html`
```

The problem is that when trying to run the tests jest complains saying:

```
Component 'MyComponent' is not resolved:
  - templateUrl: ./my-compv1.component.html
Did you run and wait for 'resolveComponentResources()'?
```

The weird thing is that in the error the templateUrl is resolved fine.

Reading other questions I tried to set `skipNgcc: false` on the jest preset and also `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` in the tsconfig.spec.json but nothing solved the issue